# Respones Notification

Tags: java, timer, notifications, response, action

I want to know how can I know if the user dose not response to the notification?
I have yes and no actions , I want when the user press yes do nothing and when he click no will send sms message and when he did not response at all there will be a timer for 20 second when it finish it will also send sms message , everything work fine but the question is how can I know if the user didn't response at all to these actions?
in this code the timer start even if the user response which is not correct.
pleeeeas help I'm dying here!

Thank you,

public void notification(){
    String title= getString(R.string.alarm);

```
//No
Intent activityIntent=new Intent(this, controllingScreen.class);
PendingIntent contentPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,activityIntent,0);
Intent actionActivityIntent=new Intent(this, SMS.class);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,0,actionActivityIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//yes
Intent activityIntentYes=new Intent(this, controllingScreen.class);
PendingIntent contentPendingIntentYes=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,activityIntentYes,0);
Intent actionActivityIntentYes=new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntentYes=PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,0,actionActivityIntentYes,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Vibrator v=(Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

NotificationManager manager;
manager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(controllingScreen.this,App.CHANNEL_ONE_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,getString(R.string.yes) ,actionPendingIntentYes)
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,getString(R.string.no) ,actionPendingIntent)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setColor(Color.BLUE)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .build();

v.vibrate((1000));


manager.notify(1,notification);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
try {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    Intent sms2 = new Intent(controllingScreen.this, SMS.class);
    startActivity(sms2);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}